# Derive PDF from MGF and Random Variable Support

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, fourier-transform, density-function, characteristic-functions

> A random variable $Y$ with support $R_Y=(-\infty, \infty)$ has moment generating function $$M_Y(t)=\left( \frac{\theta^t \Gamma(k+t)}{\Gamma(k)} \right)^n$$ where $\theta\in(0,\infty), k\in(0,\infty), n\in\mathbb{N},$ and $\Gamma(\cdot)$ represents the gamma function.  What is the probability density function of $Y$?

Truthfully, I'm unfamiliar with the characteristic function and inverse Fourier transforms, which seems to be the typical approach to solving these types of problems.  Further, this seems like a particularly challenging problem since $t$ appears as both the argument to the Gamma function and in $\theta^t$.

**Is it possible to actually derive this PDF?  If so, can you do it?**

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function -   link may help.